# Python CX_Oracle - Multiple Connections to different databases possible?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to two databases (two different hosts) using cx_Oracle in python. It appears that the client is still set to the first connection `db1` when I create instance of `db2`. Trying to close the connection and delete the variable in the process didn't help.

```
#Retrieve Data from Databases
db1 = OracleDatabaseConnector(".env_db1")
df_db1 = db1.execute_query(qry)
db1.con.close()
del db1


db2 = OracleDatabaseConnector(".env_db2")  #db2 is not correctly initialized - instance has still information of db1
df_db2 = db2.execute_query(qry2)  #Error is: Ora-00942 Table or View does not exist - as still connected to db1 
db2.con.close()
del db2
```

OracleDatabaseConnector's `db.con` is based on `cx_Oracle.connect()`

I found this [Github Comment](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/389#issuecomment-631769320), but the provided code does not work on my setup `Oracle 19c on-prem`.

Any help much appreciated!

**Edit** Additional Info for `OracleDatabaseConnector`

```
class OracleDatabaseConnector:
    def __init__(self, env_file_path: str):
        self.env = env_file_path
        load_dotenv(self.env)

        self.con = self.__get_connection()


    def __get_connection(self):
        dsn = oracledb.ConnectParams(host=os.environ.get("HOSTNAME")
                                , port=os.environ.get("PORT")
                                ,          service_name=os.environ.get("SERVICE_NAME")
                        ).get_connect_string()

         return oracledb.connect(user=os.environ.get("USER")
                            , password=os.environ.get("PASS")
                            , dsn=dsn)

   def execute_query(self, sql_qry: str):
       try:
           return pd.read_sql_query(sql_qry, self.con)
       except:
           print("Error executing SQL Query!")
           raise Exception
```

**EDIT 2** Added DSN Info of both connections (after upgrade to python-oracledb library).

```
db1.con.dsn
Out[5]: '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=hostname_db1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=db1_SERVICE_NAME_APP)))'

db2.con.dsn
Out[6]: '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=hostname_db1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=db1_SERVICE_NAME_APP)))'
```

DSN String for both connections the same. I checked the two `.env` files. They include the corresponding correct credentials and client information.

Comment: It's not clear what is going on inside your `OracleDatabaseConnector` initialization. If you are successfully authenticated in the second database (which I suppose is done in `__init__`, not in `execute_query`), then it seems that multiple wallets described in link is not an issue and we need more details for this class to help.

Comment: @astentx - I added the information of `OracleDatabaseConnector`  to my post - Thanks!

Comment: Does the SQL behind qry2 work as expected in second database when you connect to it with a tool like SQL Developer? I am trying to understand why the ORA-0942 gives you the impression that you are still connected to the first database.

Comment: What "doesn't work" with respect to the GitHub comment you referenced? Are you connecting to multiple cloud databases? What is found in the `dsn` values?

Comment: Your example doesn't show the use of multiple cloud databases or anything more complex than host:port/service_name. Those should work just fine!

Comment: To answer the basic question: yes you can connect to multiple databases from cx_Oracle at the same time.  (A side comment: it is time to upgrade cx_Oracle.  This has a new name, python-oracledb - see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)).

Comment: @oisene - Yes the query2 that is executed in python does work e.g. in SQLDeveloper.
@AnthonyTuininga - Error was `'username' not a valid parameter` - I am not working with clouddatabases, but on-premise installations of Oracle on internal servers. 

@ChristopherJones - Thanks for the hint to upgrade to `oracledb` - However, the error persists unfortunately. Will add the dsn of the connections shortly to the post.

Comment: It seeems like the problem is with the `load_dotenv` the information does not get overwritten once the new instance of class `OracleDatabaseConnector` is created.

Comment: You need to debug the connection info, because the rest of the code should work fine for user/password auth

Answer (score 0):

Issue was not the oracle client, but for this specific case the environmental variables which were set via `load_dotenv` using the python dotenv library.

`load_dotenv` has parameter `override` which is set per default to `False`. When used like `load_dotenv('.env', override=True)` calling a second .env  file from the same script will update the os variables accordingly.

Solution found on [this github issue](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/issues/331).